# Block all IPs on website except cloudflare

Tags: .htaccess, webserver, litespeed, openlitespeed

I'm using LiteSpeed Webserver on cPanel. I want to block all IPs except Cloudflare IP ranges.

This is my code (in my .htaccess file), however, it always results in a 403 forbidden error even when i'm accessing my website through cloudflare proxy:

```
# Cloudflare IPv4
allow from 173.245.48.0/20
allow from 103.21.244.0/22
allow from 103.22.200.0/22
allow from 103.31.4.0/22
allow from 141.101.64.0/18
allow from 108.162.192.0/18
allow from 190.93.240.0/20
allow from 188.114.96.0/20
allow from 197.234.240.0/22
allow from 198.41.128.0/17
allow from 162.158.0.0/15
allow from 104.16.0.0/13
allow from 104.24.0.0/14
allow from 172.64.0.0/13
allow from 131.0.72.0/22

# Cloudflare IPv6
allow from 2400:cb00::/32
allow from 2606:4700::/32
allow from 2803:f800::/32
allow from 2405:b500::/32
allow from 2405:8100::/32
allow from 2a06:98c0::/29
allow from 2c0f:f248::/32

# Deny all other 
deny from all
```

Tried rearranging the code, and verified that the IP ranges are correct, but it still does not work.

Comment: You should also have an `Order Deny,Allow` directive (in that order) - although that is the default (on Apache at least). Have you confirmed that the IP address reaching your application server (and the one being denied) falls in to one of the IP ranges stated? Any other directives in the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: It turns out that the shared cPanel serevr im using has some sort of plugin that sees the website visitor's real IP instead of a Cloudflare server IP

Comment: Ah, probably [mod_remoteip](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_remoteip.html).